# How do I call php script each time html file loads?

Tags: php, html

I have php script that counts web site visits. I need to call that script each time my html page loads.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a PHP page, you can include/require a page in to another PHP page using `require` or `include` see [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) documentation

```
require("counting_script.php");
// or
include("counting_script.php");
```

If it's a purely HTML file, then you could consider using an iFrame to load your other page see [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

```
<iframe src="page_counter.php"></iframe>
```

Or if you know jQuery, you could make an ajax call (using jQuery) to your counting page.  See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get('page_counter.php', function(data) {
  alert('Counter page was called');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some webpages uses a transparent 1x1 pixel image that can count number of requests, it works by letting PHP return a image. This is the code for image.php:

```
header('Content-type: image/gif');
echo chr(71).chr(73).chr(70).chr(56).chr(57).chr(97).chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(128).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(33).chr(249).chr(4).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(44).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).chr(2).chr(2).chr(68).chr(1).chr(0).chr(59);
```

So now you simply create the correct HTML for it like this:

```
<img src="image.php"/>
```

Notice that you also can send variables and other useful information to your PHP-file with arguments like:

```
<img src="image.php?username=test"/>
```

You also recieve a lot of other useful information in this approach like being able to use the $_SERVER-variables to determine what URL the user saw when the image.php file was requested, so now you are able to make per-page statistics.

Comment: I liked this better than using an IFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to use an img tag

```
<img src="page_counter.php" alt="counter"/>
```

and inside your page_counter.php file

```
<?php 
//your php counter script

//return an 1x1 transparent image
$image = file_get_contents('your_path/1x1.png'); 
header('content-type: image/png'); 
echo $image;
?>
```