# Execute php script on every request to the server

Tags: apache

Is it possible to run a separate php script on every HTTP request to the server regardless of how it's being handled later on?

`auto_prepend_file` runs on the same process and only works if the request is eventually handled by a php script, however if the server returns 301 redirect it won't execute.

```
# apache conf file
php_value auto_prepend_file run.php
```

In addition, forking via [pcntl_fork](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) doesn't work under Apache.

Comment: Interesting. I am also wondering how. That would help me a lot too. Let me try to find a solution :D Might be impossible because .htaccess file might be our only hope, and .htaccess can't open files ??? I am really confused lol. Maybe you can use cron jobs? What does the PHP file do?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945422/how-do-i-call-php-script-each-time-html-file-loads. Might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call php script each time html file loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945422/how-do-i-call-php-script-each-time-html-file-loads)